# Resetable fuse leakage

Tags: protection, fuses, ptc

I'm planning to use Resetable fuse PTC for cable protection of a sensor's cable.
The sensor will not draw more than 40mA.

So considering that PTC is not accurate and its affected by temperature I  choose this
[image]

so in case the environment get to 80C it will have **I-hold** of 70mA (50%)
[image]

But the question comes to the trip resistance. as these PTCs have leakage current and trip resistance. I cant find it in datasheet .. I think its good to know it to have parallel fault led near it? and to have way to notify the controller that the fault occurred..

Comment: Do you really need to protect the cable to your sensors? Is your circuit capable of putting so much current through them in the event of a short that they could overheat and cause damage?

Comment: im having 24V from power supply to circuit and then from circuit to sensor direct pcb track @Finbarr